# How to insert string type timestampto in to sql server 2008 r2 table

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am trying to insert records from excel file into database table. The excel file contains time stamp as "05/10/13 03:47 PM IST". I want to save the time stamp in db as datetime, so that later i may able to fire query on datetime constraint. In java i am using prepared statement. I am using datetime2(7) data type in table.

> value of timeStampt = 05/10/13 03:47 PM IST

```
private void insertToDb(String vh, String timeStamp, String location, double tempReal, double tempFixed) throws ParseException{
        conn = DbHandler.getConnection();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm a");
        java.util.Date utilDate = sdf.parse(timeStamp);

        java.sql.Date sqlDate =  new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

        String query = "INSERT INTO [DATALOGGER_TEMP_REPORT](vehicle_no,time_stamp,location,temp_real,temp_fixed)values(?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {
            pstmt= conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1,vh);
            pstmt.setDate(2, sqlDate);//(2, date);
            pstmt.setString(3, location );
            pstmt.setDouble(4, tempReal);
            pstmt.setDouble(5, tempFixed);
            pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute insert statement
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

> Currently, In database table timestamp value is stored as = 2013-10-05 00:00:00.0000000
>
> Rather, i want my table to store timestamp as 05/10/13 03:47 PM IST

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try it with the `java.sql.Timestamp` type instead of `java.sql.Date`. This should be appropriate. It works the same way as with `java.sql.Date`.

Your code would then contain:

```
....
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTS = new.java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());

...

pstmt.setTimestamp(2, sqlTS);
...
```

Comment: java.sql.Date holds data to the millisecond, the OP is only requiring to the minute

Comment: I get 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
 at com.bfpl.servlet.UploadServlet.insertToDb(UploadServlet.java:356) when trying to change java.sql.Date to java.sql.Timestamp; 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm a");
  java.util.Date utilDate =  sdf.parse(timeStamp);
  
  java.sql.Timestamp sqlDate =  (Timestamp) utilDate;

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now. but what it is inserting data as 2013-10-18 00:22:00.0000000, i need to regenerate excel that would contain the time stamp in dd/MM/yy hh:mm a format, is there any way to convert 2013-10-18 00:22:00.0000000 back into 18/10/13 12:22 AM IST

Comment: there are 2 ways: Either you use a SQL-function inside your SELECT statement (`TO_CHAR` or `CONVERT`) and can retreive it with java by `getString` or you retrieve it as a `TimeStamp` Object. In your case, the SQL-version sounds easier, but if you want to do something else with the data in the future, a TimeSTamp object would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here depends on what type of column you are trying to store into in the sql server db.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

If you are simply using a SQL `Date` type, then this only has the accuracy of one day.

I am assuming that the `java.util.Date utilDate` is correctly holding the datetime.

Comment: java.util.Date is correctly holding the datetime but when i m trying to insert it in db, i get excelption that java.util.Date can not connvert to java.sql.Date.

Comment: Please post your exception.